# java - Calling a subclass method from dynamically casted superclass

Tags: java, class, inheritance, casting

### 1:

I have a dictionary with a string as key and a class as value, this contains a list of "entities" i have in my game.

```
private static Map<String, Class> entitiesList = new HashMap<String, Class>();
public static void initEntitiesList()
{
    entitiesList.put("npc_something", NpcSomething.class);
    entitiesList.put("npc_thing", NpcThing.class);
    entitiesList.put("npc_stuff", NpcStuff.class);
    ...
}
```

### 2:

Here's an example hierarchy.

```
Entity (abstract)
^
Mobile (abstract)
^
BaseCreature (abstract)
^
NpcSomething
```

-Entity contains a method called `"public void Input(String args)"`,
which can be redefined in the other entities.
-When i call `Input("x")` on NpcSomething it should do a `super(arg)` chain from it's own class to Entity's class.
-All those classes above have a constructor allowing string as argument.

### 3:

I have an independent static method used to create new instances of my entities, which goes as such:

```
public static boolean createEntity(String entName, String args)
{
    Class<?> entClass = null;
    if ((entClass = entitiesList.get(entName)) != null)
    {
        Entity ent;
        try
        {
            ent = (Entity)entClass.getDeclaredConstructor(String.class).newInstance("");

            //this here failed.
            //Method method = entClass.getMethod("input", new Class[] { ent.getClass() });
            //method.invoke(ent, new Object[] {ent});
            //java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: entities.NpcSomething.input(entities.NpcSomething)

            //this here is really out of place, as i plan on having a hundred of entities and even more...
            //if (entClass.isInstance(NpcSomething.class))

            //i tried stuffs related to:
            //T t = entClass.cast(ent);
            //but i could not understand it at all even with documentation.

            //basically i want to cast ent to entClass to call Input.
            //right now, the line under calls Input on an Entity class, which is what i want to avoid.
            ent.Input("Stuffs");
        }
        catch (InstantiationException ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
        catch (IllegalAccessException ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
        catch (InvocationTargetException ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
        catch (NoSuchMethodException ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
        catch (SecurityException ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}
```

### 4:

My problem.

```
EntCreator.createEntity("NpcSomething", "stuffs");
EntCreator.createEntity("NpcThing", "stuffs");
EntCreator.createEntity("NpcStuff", "stuffs");
```

I want to call `Input();` on NpcSomething,
I want to call `Input();` on NpcThing,
I want to call `Input();` on NpcStuff.
Then those 3 will call their respective superclass code, and so on until they reach Entity.

Those are casted as Entity with `"ent = (Entity)entClass.getDec..."`, because i have Mobile, but also Item, and other classes that inherit Input.
Then with that Entity, find the right subclass, and call the Input of that said subclass.

Short line problem: Create "NpcSomething" as an "Entity" then cast the entity to "NpcSomething's class" to call the method `"Input(args)"`.

### 5:

Answers to quick questions.

-Q: Why doing this?
-A: To create entities with pre-creation arguments, example: creating a `("NpcSomething", "health 20 healthmax 25")`.

-Q: Why not using instanceof?
-A: I would need more than 200 `instanceof` in that static class, this would be a bad programming practice.

-Q: Why don't you move your input method in Entity itself?
-A: I have many different entities with different values,
 ex:
 NpcThing, the only flying mobile would have flyingSpeed, flyingEnergy...
 ItemScroll, having text, textColor, textFont...
 Those are things i can't place in Entity, as it would require `instanceof`, which is a bad practice for more than ents.

-Q: Do you want to cast NpcSomething to Entity?
-A: Read the whole thing again.

-Q: Could you provide more informations?
-A: I would love to do that too.

-Q: Why don't you declare ent as NpcSomething?
-A: because ent could be ItemStuff, ModelHouse, etc, which are not inheriting from Mobile, or BaseCreature...

### 6:

I did not find good practical examples of how to do what i want.
I could not find anything especially for this in the documentation.
Any help is welcome.

Comment: As `input` accepts a single `String` argument, you should get it by `Method method = entClass.getMethod("input", String.class);`

Comment: So, the method `Input` (why is a method name starting with capital letter) is defined with `String args...` for all the methods? Then you can call it directly. It's overridden even if the reference is to `Entity`. If the `Input` method has different parameters, then it's not really overriding. Can you please show the actual signature of the `Input` method of some of your classes?

Comment: @RealSkeptic I believe OP needs parameters to be transformed in some way depending on concrete entity class.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou not according to the comment in the source. I'm waiting for more input from OP, as he seems to be confused about OO concepts.

Comment: @RealSkeptic #5, Q3. BTW, ok, OP will explain better I suppose.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou Q3 is about "move the method to Entity". It's not about using an overridden method.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Now I'm confused. First he writes that "entity contains a method called Input(String args)", then that he cannot "move it into Entity class"...

Comment: sorry for the confusion, it is: public void input(String input).  
And it is overriden in each subclass from Entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you got the `Entity ent` instance from `newInstance()` method. This is how you invoke `input(String)` method for that instance:

```
// See here, the .class argument passed is the type of parameter
// You're using `ent.getClass()` here. It won't work
Method method = ent.getMethod("input", String.class);

// then while invoking this method, you pass the argument:
// Call `invoke()` method of `Method` class
// First arg is the instance on which this method should be called
// Remaining arg is the argument to be passed to the method itself.
result = method.invoke(ent, args);
```

Answer (score -1):

Because the method call has a higher priority than the cast.
You should force the cast before the method call by surrounding it with brackets

```
ent = ((Entity)entClass).getDeclaredConstructor(String.class).newInstance("");
```

Comment: It tells me an error: Impossible to convert Class<capture#2-of ?> to Entity

Comment: Why is entClass of type ´Class<?>´ Aren't you certain that it is of type ´Entity´?  This makes the variable entClass a Class object, which is not really what you want.

Comment: Otherwise i get something like: Impossible to convert Class<Entity> to Entity. But that's a good point i didn't see it.
Edit: i use Class to keep NpcSomething.class in the dictionary.